# SQL select query with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I use SQL queries to collect information regarding daily jobs from application in my work.
I am not so familiar with SQL but I have to write query that select me only rows from the table which are in exact status for more then exact time. I mean I have column JobStatus(string) and column StartTime(datetime) from which I have to select only these rows which JobStatus is 'waiting' and stay in this state for more then 30 min. It is important to say that the rows could change its status every signle minute that is why I need only these which JobStatus in not changed from 30min. I hope I am clear enough with my question.
Could this be done only with sql and if so have you got any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Can you provide more details and some sample data so anyone can be more clear about your problem and they may provide solution.

Comment: Here it is a example: I have id-1, jobstatus - running, starttime 2/8/2018/15:30. So let say that 15min after the start of this job it change its status from 'running' to ''waiting' and remain more the 30min with this status I have to select this row. If it stay less then 30min. I dont have to.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT JobStatus, StartTime FROM Your_Table 
WHERE JobStatus = "Waiting" 
AND 30 <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, NOW());
```

This might help you get the jobs in waiting state for more than 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

If StartTime represents the timestamp when JobStatus has been updated, you can try something like this :

```
SELECT JobStatus, StartTime FROM Your_Table WHERE StartTime = ?
```

You would change '?' by the same function you used to fill StartTime column.

I hope this would help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This retrive data with status waiting with StartTime ealier then now - 30 minutes

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE
  T.JobStatus='waiting' 
  AND T.StartTime<DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Can you add some details?

Comment: What details do you need? It simply retrive data with status `waiting` with `StartTime` ealier then now - 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes you could add that